# Any elegant syntax to deconstruct a nested property/member from a typescript imports?

Tags: node.js, typescript

Preface: just wondering if this is possible not a big deal otherwise.

```
import * as yargs from 'yargs'; // default import
```

and I want to get out the property of `port` or `argv`

Which will simplify from:

```
bootstrap(yargs.argv.port || 3000)
```

to:

```
bootstrap(port || 3000)
```

### **Question:**

Is there any good way to deconstruct port member from the yargs import module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be perfect way,

```
import { argv } from 'yargs'; // default import
const { port } = argv;
bootstrap(port || 3000);
```

**UPDATE**: If you need to set data type to port,

```
const { port } = argv;
const p: number = port;
bootstrap(p || 3000);
```

Comment: mmm let me test

Comment: side node would you know how to give port a type when is deconstructed out? And works as intended. will updated correct answer when timeout if over (tminus 8 mins)

Comment: @MatthewHarwood unfortunately we cannot set data type while importing a property of an object, but after that we can by assigning to new variable as follow `const a: number = port; bootstrap(a || 3000)`